# Tagging mp3 files in python 2.7 using eyeD3

Tags: python, mp3, echonest, eyed3

I am trying go create a taste profile for a directory of mp3 files using `python 2.7` script, but it seems there's something wrong with my `eyed3` module.

first I had to import it with 'd' instead of 'D'

```
import eyed3
```

then I had to change deprecated playlist method to `catalog.get_item_dicts()`.

but now it seems that there's something wrong with THIS method:

```
 tag = eyed3.Tag()
```

I know `python`is case sensitive, and have tried several syntaxes: `eyeD3`, `tag()`.

but terminal logs:

```
 >>'module' object has no attribute 'Tag'
```

I have followed this thread: [How to get detail (Title,Artist) from .mp3 files in python using eyed3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702179/how-to-get-detail-title-artist-from-mp3-files-in-python-using-eyed3)
with a similar question, but it wasn't resolved.

when script runs: `python personal_catalog_scanner.py -c soup -t song mp3`,

an `Echonest` song catalog is created, `mp3` files are found, but no `id`is created.

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `Tag` class is actually `eyed3.ID3.Tag`, not `eyed3.Tag`, so you can use the following:

```
tag = eyed3.ID3.Tag()
```

...or import it beforehand:

```
from eyed3.id3.tag import Tag
tag = Tag()
```