# How to get artwork into Tkinter Image using eyed3?

Tags: python, tkinter, eyed3

Similar to this question:

- [How to get detail (Title,Artist) from .mp3 files in python using eyed3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702179/how-to-get-detail-title-artist-from-mp3-files-in-python-using-eyed3)

I'd like to get music artwork from a `.m4a` file (similar to `.mp3') into Tkinter Image for displaying on a label.

For some strange reason all the answers in the link use:

```
import eyed3
```

but I have to use

```
import eyeD3
```

to install I had to use:

```
sudo apt install python-eyed3
sudo apt install eyed3
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS until 2021 at the latest which means I'm using Python 2.7.12. I understand the syntax and naming conventions may have changed in `eyeD3` or `eyed3` Python 3.5 versions which is another option for Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I'm also using Linux Kernel `4.14.188` LTS but I doubt that matters.

**Note:** I tried `ffmpeg` calls from Python this morning to convert `.m4a` file's artwork into a `.jpg` file but that was "complicated" and I was hoping `eyed3` or `eyeD3` would be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `file.tag.images` and iterate it,use `i.image_data` to get the bytes of the image.

For example:

```
import eyed3, io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
file = eyed3.load(r"music_path")

# if there contains many images
for i in file.tag.images: 
     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(i.image_data)))
     tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()

# or if there only one image here:

# img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.tag.images[0].image_data)))
# tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Works fine on my PC.
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you know I no sooner got `ffmpeg` working (finally) then read your excellent answer. I'll try it tonight and compare speeds to `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Glad to know the result of comparsion.

Comment: It will take awhile because command: `file = eyeD3.load(r'"' + self.current_song_path + '"')` generates the error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'
`. I suspect you are using Ubuntu 20.04 or similar with Python 3.8 and not Ubuntu 16.04 LTS like me with Python 2.7.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My device: `Windows 10 + Python 3.7`.The cause maybe is you are using `python2` .

Comment: I'm not able to fetch the image. It shows me a white screen instead

Comment: @KrevoL See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function, Your image maybe garbage collected by python.